# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django

I am building a project in Django Rest Framework to interact with my React app, enabling users to signup and create a profile.

However, when I run `python manage.py runserver` and click on the url appearing on API Root Page I get the following error message:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /profiles/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

Here is my models.py code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150)
    signup_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_profile_signal(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

My serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Profile

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('user', 'name', 'location', 'email', 'signup_confirmation')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from .import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'profiles', views.ProfileViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

and views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import ProfileSerializer
from .models import Profile
from .forms import SignUpForm
from .tokens import account_activation_token

class ProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

Any idea of why I am getting this error

Answer (score 3):

You are inheriting `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` in `ProfileSerializer`, and `ProfileSerializer` has a `user` field configured inside `Meta`. That means that it has to search for reverse URL of `user-detail` view (with some `pk` arg). But you have no view associated with this view name, so you get `ImproperlyConfigured`

Upd:

The simplest fix will be inheriting from `ModelSerializer` instead of `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`. Differences are

1. `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` does not include `id` field by default
2. `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` includes `url` field, that points at url of serialized instance
3. Relationships use `HyperlinkedRelatedField`, instead of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

The main reason for you to switch over to `ModelSerializer` is that you don't need to configure view names (e.g. creating viewsets) for every related model.

You can also read the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) for more details

Comment: Great explanation of the problem. Can you also give some suggestions about how to fix it?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, yeah, I updated the answer. He could've just renamed `user` to `user_id`, but I think this is not the best way to manage relations in serializers, so I didn't include that as a possible fix

Comment: One more option to add: add routes for `User`.